# How to delete list Items in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to remove the list items "snippet, contentDetails and status" if the "title" of the current object equals "Private video". Is there an easy way to do that?

Here is an example of the response JSON I receive:

```
{
    "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
    "items": [{
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Zu Tisch... im Marais Poitevien | ARTE"
            },
            "contentDetails": {
                "videoId": "HjrsjdnpcBk"
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "public"
            }
        },
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Private video"
            },
            "contentDetails": {
                "videoId": "arRStb8Hk00"
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "private"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 81
    }
}
```

This is what it should look like after the removal:

```
{
    "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
    "items": [{
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Zu Tisch... im Marais Poitevien | ARTE"
            },
            "contentDetails": {
                "videoId": "HjrsjdnpcBk"
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "public"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 81
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple list comprehension should do the trick

```
j = {
"nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
"items": [{
        "snippet": {
            "title": "Zu Tisch... im Marais Poitevien | ARTE"
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "videoId": "HjrsjdnpcBk"
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "public"
        }
    },
    {
        "snippet": {
            "title": "Private video"
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "videoId": "arRStb8Hk00"
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "private"
        }
    }
],
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 81
}
}

j['items'] = [item for item in j['items'] if item['snippet']['title'] != 'Private video']
```

Output:

```
{'nextPageToken': 'CDIQAA',
 'items': [{'snippet': {'title': 'Zu Tisch... im Marais Poitevien | ARTE'},
   'contentDetails': {'videoId': 'HjrsjdnpcBk'},
   'status': {'privacyStatus': 'public'}}],
 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 81}}
```

Comment: Did you even try this?

Comment: Yeah the output is from my jupyter notebook

Comment: @Ajay I get your point. My input wasn't the JSON itself but the decoded one. I've pasted the input to avoid confusion